# attach file to an email in c#

Tags: c#, zip, attachment, rar

How to attach some files or folders as one compressed file to an email in c# ?
For example assume I have 2 folders and 3 files and it is necessary that I attach these files and folders into one compressed file.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? There are countless examples all around the Internet.

Comment: I found somethings but these wasn't useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) for compressing the folder as there is a method exactly for this task :

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.AddDirectory("DirectoryOnDisk", "rootInZipFile");
    zip.Save("MyFile.zip");
}
```

After that you have to simply attach it to the email (

> .AddAttachment(..)

).

Comment: Can use another component for this purpose?

Comment: yes there are many zipping libraries.